# outputlink to salesforce 1 app page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, outputlink

I have a simple visualforce page that is a list of links that redirect to app pages. All the links work fine in lightning experience, but I get the following error when I try to open it in salesforce 1: "You can't open this page, either because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices". If I try to access the pages through the navigation menu it also works fine.

```
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="divTitle">
            <div>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="title" value="Relatórios de Expansão"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divSubTitle">
            <div>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="Subtitle" value="Diretoria"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/Diretoria_Expans_o');">CICLO DE EXPANSAO</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/Diretoria_Franquias');">FRANQUIAS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/Diretoria_NN_Embandeiramentos');">NN/EMBANDEIRAMENTOS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="divSubTitle">
            <div>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="Subtitle" value="Gerência Executiva"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/GE_Ciclo_de_Expans_o');">CICLO DE EXPANSAO</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/GE_Franquias');">FRANQUIAS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/GE_NN_Embandeiramentos');">NN/EMBANDEIRAMENTOS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sForce1Navigate(url) {
        if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
            console.log(url);
            sforce.one.navigateToURL(url, true);
        } else {
            window.open(url);
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the "Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app" checkbox checked for this page?

Comment: The checkbox is checked.

Comment: Are you trying to go to a visualforce page with your outputlinks or a visualforce tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some try and error I found out how salesforce1 reads app pages url. Here is working code.

```
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="divTitle">
            <div>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="title" value="Relatórios de Expansão"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divSubTitle">
            <div>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="Subtitle" value="Diretoria"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('aloha#/n/Diretoria_Expans_o');">CICLO DE EXPANSAO</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('aloha#/n/Diretoria_Franquias');">FRANQUIAS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('aloha#/n/Diretoria_NN_Embandeiramentos');">NN/EMBANDEIRAMENTOS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="divSubTitle">
            <div>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="Subtitle" value="Gerência Executiva"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('aloha#/n/GE_Ciclo_de_Expans_o');">CICLO DE EXPANSAO</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('aloha#/n/GE_Franquias');">FRANQUIAS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdivexterna">
            <div class="link">
                <apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate('aloha#/n/GE_NN_Embandeiramentos');">NN/EMBANDEIRAMENTOS</apex:outputLink>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sForce1Navigate(url) {
        if({!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4t'}) {
            sforce.one.navigateToURL(url, true);
        } else if ({!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}){
            window.open('/one/one.app?source='+url);
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```